# MS Access needed for VB6 program?

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6

I've written a program in VB6. It is connected to an Access database.

When I run the exe on an other computer, I'm getting the following error message:
Run-time error 713: Application-defined or object-defined error.

This computer does not have office installed. Can this be the cause of this error message? Do I need to install office on this computer to be able to connect VB6 with an Access database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is the Access database? Access 2003, Access 2007 or what? How are you connecting to the database? ADO, DAO? Can you show a connection string? On which line of code does the error occur (add logging or add an error handler)

Answer (score 4):

Access has two parts, the "back-end" Jet or ACE database and the "front-end" application. You do not need Access to use Jet. You need ACE, which is free to download if you reference the ACE drivers. You need Access if you reference the Access application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've just installed Microsoft Access Database Engine. Is this what you mean? What exactly do you mean with "reference the ACE drivers"? Do I need to select this in the project references of my VB6 project? I can't find ACE in the list. Also I'm using DataEnvironment of VB6. I hope this isn't causing the problem?

Comment: You say "It is connected to an Access database" How is it connected? I am afraid your question is quite vague. There is no code and no details for your error.